# VHDL generic case statement

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I am trying to instantiate a mux with a generic number of case statements. Currently my code looks like this:

In these examples data_array and selector are inputs, data is the output and the width of the mux is 4.

```
process(all)
begin
    case? selector is
        when "1---" => data <= data_array(3);
        when "01--" => data <= data_array(2);
        when "001-" => data <= data_array(1);
        when "0001" => data <= data_array(0);
        when others => data <= (others => '-');
    end case?;
end process;
```

Is there a way to have a generic number of case statements? Or is there a similar feature that I could use?

I could solve this using code generation to generate the appropriate number of case statements but I was wondering if there is a VHDL(-2008) feature that I could use to solve this.

I have rewritten the mux to use a for loop but unfortunately my implementation tool is not handling this very well. The logic that is inferred is not optimal and quite bad in terms of timing.

In this example GENERIC_WIDTH is the width of the mux.

```
process(all)
begin
    data_v := (others => '0');
    for i in 0 to GENERIC_WIDTH-1 loop
        if selector(i) then
            data <= data_array(i);
        end if;
    end loop;
end process;
```

I am targeting a Xilinx device using Vivado 2017.3. Implementation results show that using the case statement yields more efficient logic (in terms of WNS and logic depth) than using the for loop.

Comment: Using recursion can sometimes solve problems like this: instead of some long, thin topology with a long delay through it, you can generate a tree structure, which depending on the number of nodes, could have a much shorter delay through it (roughly log2). This is not an easy thing to do, however. Basically, you want recursive instantiation, where each instance divides the problem into two and the recursion keeps going until the bottom, where the problem becomes trivial.

Comment: In your second code example, what happens if you add the line `exit;` after `data <= data_array(i);`? I would expect this to give the same output as your first example. Also, assuming your `selector` has a `downto` range, your for loop should also use a `downto` range, in order to match the matching case statement.

Comment: I'm missing a [mcve] to be able to verify you issue. So you are saying that the first code fragment produces more efficient logic then the second code fragment for `GENERIC_WIDTH:=4`?

Comment: See my edit: all code appears to be synthesized the same. This seems to be a case of expectations. The logic you describe is a chain of multiplexers. If you set `GENERIC_WIDTH` to a large number, the resource use and delay will become large. That is inevitable.

Comment: Yes, I understand that there is a fundamental limit to how many logic levels you can have for a certain reg to reg path. What interested me more in this case was post implementation changes in timing.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter anymore: modern synthesis tools will correctly optimize all logic. I made a comparison between Vivado 2017.3 outputs. The base entity is

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity MyMux is
    generic(
        data_width : positive := 32;
        data_depth : positive := 4
    );
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        data_in : in std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);
        selector : in std_logic_vector(data_depth-1 downto 0);
        data_out : out std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;
```

Architecture 1:

```
architecture rtl of MyMux is
    subtype data_type is std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);
    type data_array_type is array (0 to data_depth-1) of data_type;

    signal data_array : data_array_type := (others => (others => '0'));
begin
    read_data : process(clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            for i in data_depth-1 downto 1 loop
                data_array(i) <= data_array(i-1);
            end loop;
            data_array(0) <= data_in;
        end if;
    end process;

    select_output: process(all) begin
        case? selector is
            when "1---" => data_out <= data_array(3);
            when "01--" => data_out <= data_array(2);
            when "001-" => data_out <= data_array(1);
            when "0001" => data_out <= data_array(0);
            when others => data_out <= (others => '-');
        end case?;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Architecture 2:

```
architecture rtl of MyMux is
    subtype data_type is std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);
    type data_array_type is array (0 to data_depth-1) of data_type;

    signal data_array : data_array_type := (others => (others => '0'));
begin
    read_data : process(clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            for i in data_depth-1 downto 1 loop
                data_array(i) <= data_array(i-1);
            end loop;
            data_array(0) <= data_in;
        end if;
    end process;

    select_output: process(all) begin
        data_out <= (others => '-');
        for i in 0 to data_depth-1 loop
            if selector(i) then
                data_out <= data_array(i);
            end if;
        end loop;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Architecture 3:

```
architecture rtl of MyMux is
    subtype data_type is std_logic_vector(data_width-1 downto 0);
    type data_array_type is array (0 to data_depth-1) of data_type;

    signal data_array : data_array_type := (others => (others => '0'));

    function my_mux(
        selector : std_logic_vector(data_depth-1 downto 0);
        data_array : data_array_type) return data_type is
        variable data : data_type;
    begin
        data := (others => '-');
        for i in 0 to data_depth-1 loop
            if selector(i)='1' then
                data := data_array(i);
            end if;
        end loop;
        return data;
    end function;
begin
    read_data : process(clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            for i in data_depth-1 downto 1 loop
                data_array(i) <= data_array(i-1);
            end loop;
            data_array(0) <= data_in;
        end if;
    end process;

    data_out <= my_mux(selector, data_array);
end architecture;
```

Output:

- Architecture 1: 32 LUT3, 32 LUT6, 128 FDRE
- Architecture 2: 32 LUT3, 32 LUT5, 128 FDRE
- Architecture 3: 32 LUT3, 32 LUT5, 128 FDRE

So they are all practically the same.

The problem is you case seems to be the non deterministic component: initial placement randomization. In my experience this initial placement is based on some randomizer seed extracted from the hash of the code. The same code will always give the same implementation. But make a very small change in the code, and timing and resource use might be completely different.

You should take note that the logic you describe in you code will implement as a chain of multiplexers. When the `GENERIC_WIDTH` increases, so will the delay. This is inevitable.

Comment: While it's good to use abstractions, I would not expect a function to make any synthesis difference here : that "fully evaluated first" is just "multiplexers and gates". Of course specific synth tools may not make the expected translation...

Comment: @BrianDrummond It should not make a difference, and maybe it doesn't anymore. But in my experience, back in 2010-2012 when I was doing a lot of this stuff using Xilinx ISE, I really noticed that the synthesis tool would mess up logic in process loops, which I could resolve using function loops.

Comment: That is very interesting! I did actually notice that post synth the results similar. Results seem to vary after implementation. That makes assessment extra difficult because the implementation strategies have a non deterministic component (e.g. changing the whitespace results in meeting timing/not meeting timing). I'll update the original post with more timing exploration and compare with you're suggestions.

Comment: Come to think about it, if the synth result is the same than the only thing that can change during implementation is the non deterministic component. I'll do more timing exploration.

Comment: @Maurice indeed, placement especially is such a large search space that finding a (the?) optimal solution is impossible; something like a genetic or annealing algorithm is used, starting from a randomised placement generated from the source and a seed. Classic ISE PAR allowed you to run "Multi-pass place/route" aka MPPR with a different seed for each pass and pick the best - maybe Vivado has the same?. Sadly, with the foresight common to so much Xilinx software, it was aggressively single-threaded, however many CPUs you had available. A shell script ...

Comment: A shell script spawning multiple PAR runs, each with a different seed via a command line option, was one way round this limitation. @JHBonarius +1 for seriously good investigation yb the way.